# Powershell Loop two files

Tags: file, loops, powershell

I have Googled for this for quite a while today, and cannot seem to solve my problem.  I have a file with names one on each line:

```
    file1.txt
    -----
    name1
    name2
    name3/
```

In Powershell I pass these to a cmdlet:

```
    Get-Content file1.txt | ForEach-Object {
        Get-XYZ -Name $_ -Type HTML -Path $_
    }
```

Issue is the -Path parameter will not accept the /, but the Name parameter needs it to function. I have tried to write the paths needed into a file wrapped in quotes:

```
    Get-Content file1.txt | ForEach-Object {
        '"C:\' + $_ + '.htm"'
    } > file2.txt
```

Issue is then I have two files so I try:

```
    $var1 = Get-Content file2.txt

    Get-Content file1.txt | ForEach-Object {
        Get-XYZ -Name $_ -Type HTML -Path $var1 
    }
```

Then I get errors that $var1 is an array and not a string.  Is there a way to do:

```
    Get-Content file1.txt,file2.txt | ForEach-Object {
        Get-XYZ -Name $_ -Type HTML -Path $$__
    }
```

Where $_ is the first line in file1.txt and $$__ is the first like in file2.txt?  I realize that $$__ is not a real thing but just wondering if there is  away to reference the first line from each file in that statement.  If not what would be a good approach to this?  I have tried so many things this is just a basic example of where I am trying to go.

Comment: `Issue is the -Path parameter will not accept the /, but the Name parameter needs it to function.` - then address this issue directly. What is `Get-XYZ` and how does it make sense that you need to call it with parameters it cannot accept? Surely the file's path cannot be `C:\name3/.htm` ?

Comment: Get-XYZ inputs a name from the text file into the -Name parameter which works fine and some of the names contain characters like / which Powershell wont allow to be used in a filename.  I need to save the file out exactly as the name is with .htm after it so the file gets saved to C:\ for example and the name of the file would be name3/.htm if I do this the manual way via the microsoft MMC for the cmdlet it will save the file as name3/.htm no problem.

Comment: I stand corrected that I do not need to / in the filename but I do need it to be named after the same input used in -Name parameter with the .htm extension.  So if I could replace / with a _ that would work and I know how to do that.  My problem is I dont know how to pass that as a second variable into the -Path parameter, and still have each line stay together so I dont end up with -Name name1 and -Path name3_

Comment: In your first attempt, could you use `-Name $_ -Type HTML -Path ($_ replace '/', '_')` and no need for the second file at all?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly!  With the one exception that I need to now at .htm to the end of the filename.  I have tried + '.htm' on the inside of the () as well as outside with no luck so far.

Comment: Good progress; wouldn't the `.htm` go on the -Name property rather than the -Path? Oh my comment should have said `-replace` and then I'd expect either `-Name "$_.htm"` or `-Path ($_ -replace '/', '_') + '.htm'` to work, whichever is appropriate

Comment: Thank you!  I had figured out the .htm before seeing your comment, and had added the - to replace before also so this is what ended up doing the trick:
        Get-XYZ -Name $_ -ReportType HTML -Path ("C:\report\" + $_ + ".htm" -replace '/', '_')

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$_ -replace '\\|/', '_'` will be a regex replacement which matches \\ or / , or you could do `$_.Replace('\', '_').Replace('/', '_')`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing `/` for the path value.

```
Get-Content file1.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Get-XYZ -Name $_ -Type HTML -Path ($_ -replace '/$')
}
```